# Bash - running script as it was executed in its own folder

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script called `my-script.sh` inside a folder 2 level up from the root where I want this script to be called/executed from

```
/folder1
    /folder2/
        - my-script.sh
        - do-it.sh
```

my-script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
./do-it.sh
```

If I execute `my-script.sh` from the root folder it fails since it tries to find `do-it.sh` in the same folder.

```
folder1/folder2/my-script.sh: line 3: ./do-it.sh: No such file or directory
```

If I want to execute my-script.sh script properly I have to get into folder2 first and them execute it

```
cd /folder1/folder2
./my-script.sh
```

Is there a way to execute it from root folder as it was being executed from folder2?

Answer (score 5):

To make my scripts run anywhere I usually add this line to get the folder containing the script

```
script_folder="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
$script_folder/my-script.sh
```

Comment: Very neat solution. You may want to consider to `cd $script_folder` before executing `my-script.sh`, as then the context of `my-script.sh` is also inside `folder2`

Comment: I think you meant $script_folder/do-it.sh

Answer (score 1):

I found a short and simple solution using **dirname $0**

**my-script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
./$(dirname $0)/do-it.sh
```

Comment: This is a simplified version of my answer above, it should mostly work.
Be careful though : your version can break in a number of cases, see this other post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/how-do-i-get-the-directory-where-a-bash-script-is-located-from-within-the-script

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to run a script from a certain directory is simply by mentioning the directory when running the script, so in your case:

Where-ever you are, you want to run the script as present in the `/folder1/folder2` folder:

```
sh /folder1/folder2/my-script.sh
```

Where-ever you are, you want to run the script as present in the root folder:

```
sh /my-script.sh
```

As far as the `do-it.sh` is concerned: you can create a `do-it.sh` in your root folder, containing the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
sh /folder1/folder2/do-it.sh
```

Comment: I don't want edit the script if files are moved to another directory